# Joining Dataframe with multiple dates (Vlookup)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following in a file below and was wondering how to join them together, I know how to join if they were two separate dataframe but the values range from D1 up to D20+ and will not be practical to create so many multiple dataframes. My objective is to join them based on D1 date as per below.

```
    D1           D1value  D2           D2value  D3           D3value   
    1/2/2018     21.14    1/2/2018     11.14    1/6/2018     1.55
    1/3/2018     19.13    1/3/2018     51.14    1/13/2018    2.66
    1/6/2018     19.89    1/14/2018    31.14    1/14/2018    3.77
    1/13/2018    20.24   
    1/14/2018    20.91
```

After joining it should be

```
    D1           D1value  D2value  D3value   
    1/2/2018     21.14    11.14    NaN
    1/3/2018     19.13    51.14    NaN
    1/6/2018     19.89    NaN      1.55 
    1/13/2018    20.24    NaN      2.66
    1/14/2018    20.91    31.14    3.77
```

Any kind advise please?

For piRSquared answer add df:

```
df = pd.concat([proc(d) for k, d in df.groupby(g, 1)], axis=1)
```

Both piRSquared and jp_data_analysis answer works
The issue is I want to select both as the right answer!

Comment: did you try `pd.concat([d1,d2,d3], axis=1)` already ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that columns come in adjacent pairs.

```
def proc(d):
    v = d.dropna().values
    return pd.Series(v[:, 1], pd.to_datetime(v[:, 0]), name=d.columns[1])

g = np.arange(len(df.columns)) // 2
pd.concat([proc(d) for k, d in df.groupby(g, 1)], axis=1)

           D1value D2value D3value
2018-01-02   21.14   11.14     NaN
2018-01-03   19.13   51.14     NaN
2018-01-06   19.89     NaN    1.55
2018-01-13   20.24     NaN    2.66
2018-01-14   20.91   31.14    3.77
```

---

**Setup**
I'm assuming your file looks exactly like this:

```
D1,D1value,D2,D2value,D3,D3value
1/2/2018,21.14,1/2/2018,11.14,1/6/2018,1.55
1/3/2018,19.13,1/3/2018,51.14,1/13/2018,2.66
1/6/2018,19.89,1/14/2018,31.14,1/14/2018,3.77
1/13/2018,20.24,,,,
1/14/2018,20.91,,,,
```

I read it in with

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Hi piRSquared thanks for the reply, I am trying to learn how to use your function, I have:
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\test.csv')
[[Your code]]
print (df)

But the df did not change. Able to advise me please?

Comment: @JNg read the file first into a dataframe `df` then proceed to use my code as I've written it.

Comment: It gives the following error IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: @JNg I'm afraid that isn't enough to go on.  Edit your post with the exact contents of a file so that we have no ambiguity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165340/discussion-between-j-ng-and-pirsquared).

Comment: @JNg I still don't know what your csv actually looks like.  And in your screenshot, you get an error before your `df` prints.  I don't have excel to type in the data and save to a csv.  However, you can just paste the contents of the csv into your post.

Comment: I added the contents of the CSV file to the post thanks

Comment: @JNg ty, I just read that with `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')`

Comment: Thanks I changed to read_csv but the dataframe did not change, I attached the screenshot, can you advise what I did wrong please? :D

Comment: I solved this mistake I forgot to add df, df = pd.concat([proc(d) for k, d in df.groupby(g, 1)], axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
import pandas as pd

n = 3

# convert date columns from strings to datetimes
df.loc[:, ['D'+str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]] = \
df.loc[:, ['D'+str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# create dataframe
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(df.set_index('D'+str(i))['D'+str(i)+'value']).dropna() \
                for i in range(1, n+1)], axis=1)

#             D1value  D2value  D3value
# 2018-01-02    21.14    11.14      NaN
# 2018-01-03    19.13    51.14      NaN
# 2018-01-06    19.89      NaN     1.55
# 2018-01-13    20.24      NaN     2.66
# 2018-01-14    20.91    31.14     3.77
```

Comment: Thanks jp_data_analysis, this works actually, but my n=3 may not be ok for me because my df can expand and can have an issue

Comment: @JNg, sure. You can always retrieve `n` via `df.columns` or similar. piR's solution should work as well.

Comment: Thanks jp_data_analysis, I used n = len(df.columns) // 2 as per your advise, it worked well :D

Comment: @JnG, excellent. Feel free to accept one of ours solutions (tick on left) if they helped!

Comment: I want to select both of yours and piRSquared as the right answer, I feel bad to give only one of you guys! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also use join function in pandas:

```
df = D1.join(D2.set_index('D2'), on = 'D1', how = 'left')
df = D1.join(D3.set_index('D3'), on = 'D1', how = 'left')
...
```

Now you could see the pattern and try to use loop to call D2, D3 ... to generalize this.